# How to get Solana address from wallet adapter

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, walletadapter

I can get **public key** from wallet adapter, so how to convert it to **address** in Solana ?

Comment: I'm confused. The public key is _the_ address. Do you mean base 58 representation of the public key?

Comment: Yeah, Public Key it self is the address. If you want base58 representation use `.toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The terms ‘public key’ and ‘address’ are interchangeable. The public key of a wallet is the wallet’s address.

At a fundamental level, the address is a 256-bit number. In practice you see addresses encoded in various formats, like base58 or base64.

Given a `PublicKey` object from `@solana/wallet-adapter` you can obtain its base58 representation like this:

```
const base58Pubkey = publicKey.toBase58();
```